# RegExp Problem in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find every url in text and wrap them with a tag (`<a href="...">...</a>`).

```
var src = "bla blaaa blaaaaaa 1  http://yahoo.com  text something about and. http://www.google.com";
var match = /http:\/\/([a-z0-9.-]+)/.exec(src); //this only can one matched
// result: ["http://yahoo.com", "yahoo.com"]
```

But i need to wrap every links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/g` (global) to match all occurences and the backreference like this:

```
var src = "bla blaaa blaaaaaa 1  http://yahoo.com  text something about and. http://www.google.com";
var match = src.replace(/http:\/\/([a-z0-9.-]+)/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GjHU5/1/).

Comment: First of all the link is great that i didn't know before. Secondly  thank you for `/g` explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = src.replace(/(http:\/\/([a-z0-9.-]+))/g, '<a href="$1">$2</a>');
```

Outputs:

`bla blaaa blaaaaaa 1  <a href="http://yahoo.com">yahoo.com</a>  text something about and. <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>`

Not sure that was the intention, but what I could think of. Use `<a href="$1">$1</a>` as replacement if you want to preserve the `http://` prefix in the link text, too.

(In the meantime Nick Craver provided the answer *and* introduced the `g` modifier.)

Comment: `\0` isn't a backreference, you can test it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9beM2/

Comment: @Nick Craver Nope, that's what I found out, too :-S Edited. Thanks for noting.

Comment: if i use `<a href="$1">$2</a>` i think it will use first link on second address like `<a href="yahoo.com">google.com</a>` and all these links don't open the real page because of they don't have `http://` do they ?!?

Comment: @uzay95 [No](http://jsfiddle.net/Fak6T/), the first capturing group (`$1`) is the first parenthesis (I added those to the pattern), the second (`$2`) is without the `http://` prefix. BTW `<a href="www.google.com">` is not a link to http://www.google.com/ but to the *relative* resource `www.google.com`!